# Word length function on subgroup

Tags: group-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Let $G$ be a group finitely generated by a set $S$ with $S=S^{-1}$. The word length of an element $g \in G$ (with respect to $S$)  is defined as
\begin{eqnarray}
|g|_S:= \min \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid s_1...s_n =g \text{ for some }s_1,...,s_n\in S\}.
\end{eqnarray}

For a subgroup $H \leq G$, can we always find a finite generating set $T \subseteq H$ such that the restriction of $| \cdot |_S$ to $H$ coincides with the word length coming from $T$? If no, what about the case where $H$ is a (finite index) normal subgroup?

Comment: So if $S=\{a,b,c\}$ and $H$ is generated by the word $abc$, what would you choose for $T$?  $T=\{abc\}$ would result in $|abc|_H=1$, or not?

Comment: You cannot even always find a finite generating set for $H$. But even if $H$ is finitely generated, its word metric need not be equivalent to the one restricted from $G$. One of the simplest examples comes from the integer Heisenberg group and its derived subgroup. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490288/algorithm-for-finitely-presented-torsion-free-nilpotent-groups/490393#490393). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347837/word-metric-on-a-finitely-generated-subgroup-versus-the-word-metric-of-its-finit/3349561#3349561).

Comment: Your wording is a bit off, I'd suggest double checking the problem. If G is a finite group generated by S, and S = S^-1, then the group is just {1, S}. I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant to imply.

Comment: @Moishe Nice. The links you posted are very interesting!

Comment: @sanketalekar It seems like you didn'read carefully. $S$ is not a generator but a generating set. $S^{-1}$ denotes the set of all $s^{-1}$ where $s \in S$.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I read "generated by set S" as "the objects in G are sets and S generates it".

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely not true. Consider the abelian group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ with generators $S=\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$, then $|(1, 1)|_S=2$. But the subgroup generated by $(1, 1)$ has exactly one possible symmetric generating set i.e. $T=\{(1, 1)\}$ itself, and $|(1, 1)|_T = 1$. In this example, $H$ is normal and of finite index.

In general, it's just wrong to think the word metric as precise, but only the equivalence class based on quasi-isometry matters.

Comment: It is wrong to say that the infinite cyclic group has exactly one symmetric generating set.

Comment: Isn't the question assuming $S$ is fixed, whether $T$ can be found?

Comment: Yes, and so? What you wrote is still wrong.

Comment: OK. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Now, it is correct. +1.